# Windows 7 VPN how to not tunnel internet?

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I just put windows 7 on my work laptop and im setting it all up like it used to be. But i cant remember what option i changed to stop my internet traffic being tunneled over the VPN connection. I only want to connect to exchange and intranet over VPN.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found it, it wasnt where i thought it would be.

VPN Connection -> properties -> networking -> TCP/IP 4 -> advanced -> dont use this as default gateway