# How to use simultaneous vpn connections through Windows 7 and bind each to a specific program?

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I'm trying to define my problem through an example:
Here's deal, think I have 2 vpn connections:

1. To my work place
2. To my university

And an Internet connections (totally 3 connections) and here's two problems:

---

1. How do I connect to each vpn directly through my Internet connection not another VPN?

   If I first connect to VPN1 and then connect to VPN2 the result is VPN2 is connected through VPN1 and not directly to my Internet connection. So it slow down the speed of my connection and disconnecting from VPN1 will lead to disconnecting from VPN2,  I what both be connected to their server through my original Internet connection so there will be no interrelation between the VPN connections
2. How to bind

   - VPN1 to my workplace specific application (Client of Automation system for e.g)
   - VPN2 to my webbrowser so I can attend to live classes
   - Direct Internet Connection to my download manager

The platform is Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

If the VPN clients allow it (many 3rd party ones don't (Juniper, etc.), depending on the receiving end's setup), or if you're using Windows internal VPN connection system, then you have to ensure you've told it to NOT use the remote network's gateway.

See: [Windows 7 VPN how to not tunnel internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/84990/windows-7-vpn-how-to-not-tunnel-internet)

As long as your gateway never gets assigned to something other than your normal ISP one, then you should be able to access VPN resources (you may have to use FQDN, or IPs, and/or adjust binding orders), and all other traffic that can't be resolved locally, or on either of the VPN's will use your ISP's gateway ("regular Internet").