# Using simultaneous VPN connections through Windows 7 and binding each to a specific program?

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I have three connections:

- VPN to my work place
- VPN to my university
- A direct internet connection

How do I connect to each VPN directly through my internet connection not another VPN?

If I first connect to VPN1 and then connect to VPN2 the result is VPN2 is connected through VPN1 and not directly to my internet connection. So it slows down the speed of my connection and disconnecting from VPN1 will lead to disconnecting from VPN2,  I want both to be connected to their server through my original internet connection so there will be no interrelation between the VPN connections

How do I bind:

- VPN1 to my workplace specific application (e.g., Client of Automation system)?
- VPN2 to my webbrowser so i can attend to live classes?
- Direct Internet Connection to my download manager?

(Windows 7)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use simultaneous vpn connections through Windows 7 and bind each to a specific program?](http://superuser.com/questions/366595/how-to-use-simultaneous-vpn-connections-through-windows-7-and-bind-each-to-a-spe)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "bind" VPN connections to specific programs in this way.

What you need to do is ensure that your routing table is set up to that traffic to the appropriate networks goes over the appropriate connections.

Comment: thx for your reply, so is it any best practice for this? or a tutorial?