# How do I setup my second lan interface to use my VPN?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, ethernet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 VPN how to not tunnel internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/84990/windows-7-vpn-how-to-not-tunnel-internet)

Ok so I am running Windows 7 Professional and I have 2 ethernet ports in my desktop. I would like my VPN connection to only run on the 2nd ethernet interface and all other traffic to operate in the 1st interface. Is there anyway to specify this in Windows? I thought I could go to the properties of the VPN connection->Network-> and then configure the IP settings but then I realized that was only for the connection itself.

Comment: Is your VPN connection on it's own independent network cable/Internet connection?  If not, there's no advantage in trying to use the second physical network adapter.   What is it you're trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is when I connect with the VPN and I start downloading something from the web and I disconnect before it is finished it cancels my download because it was downloading over the VPN. I want to download independently.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 VPN how to not tunnel internet?](http://superuser.com/questions/84990/windows-7-vpn-how-to-not-tunnel-internet) and/or [How can I make the Windows VPN route selective traffic (by destination network)?](http://superuser.com/questions/12022/how-can-i-make-the-windows-vpn-route-selective-traffic-by-destination-network)

Comment: You need to enable "split tunnelling".  The link above will tell you how.