# Only "lab" traffic over my Juniper VPN connection - all other traffic over normal Wifi/Ethernet?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, routing, network-interface, juniper

How do I configure my Juniper VPN client to work like the [Windows VPN](https://superuser.com/q/84990/978) client to not be the default gateway for all traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be another way to do this, but adjusting the Interface Metric under Advanced as seen in the following screenshots:

Click <kbd>Properties</kbd>

[image: first screen]

Click <kbd>Advanced</kbd>

[image: properties]

Adjust the Interface Metric to, eg, 10

[image: interface metric]

After doing this, adjust your WiFI and/or Ethernet Interface Metrics likewise (I have Ethernet set to 1, WiFi to 5, and the VPN to 10). This [should] ensure that only "appropriate" traffic goes over the VPN.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me (Windows 7, Pulse Secure Network Connect 8.2.7.54521).