# Windows 7 VPN, disable tunnel internet not working

Tags: vpn, tunnel

I'm trying to disable internet tunnel when using VPN so I can use my own internet instead of the VPN. I have unchecked this according to here

[Windows 7 VPN how to not tunnel internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/84990/windows-7-vpn-how-to-not-tunnel-internet)

VPN Connection -> properties -> networking -> TCP/IP 4 -> advanced -> dont use this as default gateway

However, my connection still routes through VPN. I know this is becos my VPN is in China, and I can't access google.com while connected.

Comment: run `print route` and `ipconfig /all` on command promopt, share your result

Comment: print route
Unable to initialize device PRN

Comment: I can't get the formatting to be correct

http://cyberversion.com/private/hla/ipconfig.jpg

Comment: In @Bilo 's comment it should've been `route print` (not the other way around)...

Comment: And for formatting things like those printouts, edit your question, paste the printout and format it as "code", then it stays readable and the information is where it should be (in the question body).